# Understanding the useness of Classification of finite simple groups

Tags: soft-question, finite-groups, automated-theorem-proving

I know that we are able to classify all the finite simple group, but I don't understand how to use this classification to prove results like that every simple group has two generators.

The difficulty is that we still have an infinite number of such groups ($ A_n $ for $ n \geq 5 $), so it seems to be very problematic to varify a conjecture via loop on all of them.

I guess I miss some important assepcts on the classification... So how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but at a very naive level the theorem can be applied in the same general way as any other classification theorem: by reducing the problem to a set of cases which are easier to analyze.

The point is that knowing that a group lies in a certain family gives us additional techniques for studying it - e.g. there are properties the alternating simple groups have, which finite simple groups don't in general. So if you want to prove something for all finite simple groups, you can break it down into a series of subproofs: one proof for each of the finitely many infinite families in the classification, together with a family of verifications for the sporadic groups individually.

That said, to the best of my knowledge the CFSG doesn't make anything *easy* - establishing that a result holds in any given case (even the individual sporadic cases!) is usually a huge task in and of itself (as you say, it can't be done by checking each individual group in the family), and indeed may need a further classification theorem breaking that individual family into finitely many sub-families. But the CFSG lets us "tie off" things once these results have been proved.

For what it's worth, you don't necessarily need to treat each infinite family separately - or, to put it another way, you only need a weaker classification theorem such as "all but finitely many of the (nonabelian) finite simple groups are either alternating or of Lie type," where we only want an asymptotic result so don't care about exactly what the sporadic cases are.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now that I had a misconception about that proof's style. I though about it as more like the Four color theorem, and now it's seems that they proved it to all of the family.

Comment: But your last paragraph seems strange to me: the proof of the statement that any finite simple group has two generators doesn't applied to every finite simple group?

Comment: @TabelleRasa I'm not sure where you're getting that. It does of course apply to every finite simple group. My point is that for some statements, you don't *need* to use the full strength of the CFSG: if a statement is asymptotic, for instance, so can ignore finitely many counterexamples. The statement "any finite group has two generators" is *not* asymptotic, so it may indeed require the full strength of CFSG.

Comment: OK, silly me, I though you meant to that statement.